# How to get rid of arrays in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Dining room specializes on complex dinners. Have collection of recipes (each of them collect rates of the products). Every product have changeable price.

Is it the best design?

```
Recipe(r_id, r_title, r_category, r_price)
Product(p_id, p_title, p_price)
UsingProducts(r_id, p_id, amount)
```

I am just not sure about UsingProducts..

Comment: "The best" from what perspective? It does not address units, for example. So at first place it is incomplete.

Comment: "The best" - according to accepted standards in mysql.

Comment: There are no such standards.

Comment: Well, i am just a newbie in mysql and i am not sure. Thanks!

Comment: Guessing at the criteria by which rows go into these tables and what your application situations can be, it is reasonable.

Comment: I'm not a fan of CamelCase - at least not as far as MySQL is concerned. Remember the Pen Island debacle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design looks quite okay.

As zerkms mentioned, you're lacking units. That doesn't have to be a problem, as your product can be "100 g flour" so the unit is implicit. However, when printing the recipe, you would print "5 x 100 g flour" instead of "500 g flour". It would also print "10 x 100 g flour" instead of "1 kilo flour".

Just think about whether this an issue for you and if you even need unit conversion like 1000 g = 1 kilo.

Another point is your category. So a recipe can only belong to one category. So you won't have something like "vegetarian" and "soups" with the problem where to place a vegetarian soup, but use distinct categories instead. Okay. However, don't you want a table for them, so to be able to easily select them? If you want to stay with this design you should at least make them an enum column (something special in MySQL), so you dont mistakenly have recipes in "soups" and others in "suops".

At last: What is the r_price for? Shouldn't that be the the sum of all sub prices (product price x amount)? Don't hold data redundantly. This must not be done. Otherwise inconsistencies can occur (e.g. 10$ + 10$ = 30$). Remove r_price from table recipe to have a normalized database.

Comment: r_price = price of cooking

Comment: btw if i need more than 1 category - i will just add 1 more table :) Isn't really problem :)